# Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have a thinkpad yoga 14, and I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it.

Wireless isn't working.

`sudo lshw -c network` has (for the relevant device):

```
zck@my-computer:~/Downloads$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d2a00000-d2a01fff
```

I downloaded the Intel Wireless WiFi Link 8260 AC Adapter, and untarred it, so now I have iwlwifi-8000C-15.ucode, and I put it in /lib/firmware as it says, but I'm not sure how to hook that up to iwlwifi, or even if that's the correct thing to do.

additional requested commands:

```
zck@my-computer:~/Downloads$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1130]
06:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] [10de:1347] (rev a2)
zck@my-computer:~/Downloads$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
zck@my-computer:~/Downloads$ dmesg | grep iwl
[ 5417.697371]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6027.901140]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6374.578584]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6389.342802]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6420.052221]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6420.996967]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6425.191771]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6425.718504]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6765.743640]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
[ 6847.871215]  iwlmvm iwlwifi mac80211 cfg80211 asix usbnet mii rfcomm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common wacom btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth videodev media nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel input_leds joydev snd_hda_codec idma64 snd_hda_core virt_dma snd_hwdep serio_raw snd_pcm intel_lpss_pci shpchp mei_me thinkpad_acpi mei nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss soundcore mac_hid acpi_pad tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` (this may produce nothing) and finally: `dmesg | grep iwl` I am only looking for any messages related to firmware. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks. I've updated the post with those three commands, and (since I got a hardwired connection), the verbatim output of `lshw`.

Comment: Please pardon my mis-step; I actually needed: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` . Sorry.

Comment: No worries. I updated the question with the new lcpci results. Also interesting is that `dmesg | grep iwl` now has results, which I've also put into the post.

Comment: I am writing an answer; it will take a few minutes. Please be patient.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your device, Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a),   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1130] is not yet covered by the driver `iwlwifi.` Several variations are covered, but not the exact pci.id and subsystem combination that you have. Let's try to add it.

Please download this file to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/09/23/backports-20150923.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.'  Drill down to drivers > net > wireless > iwlwifi > pcie. Open the file drv.c with any text editor, like gedit, nano or kate. Scroll down to line 428. Please notice that your pci.id ending in 24F3 hasn't a corresponding subsystem of 1130. 24F4 has an 1130, but not your 24F3. Let's just change it. Change line 428 from:

```
{IWL_PCI_DEVICE(0x24F4, 0x1130, iwl8260_2ac_cfg)},
```

To read instead:

```
{IWL_PCI_DEVICE(0x24F3, 0x1130, iwl8260_2ac_cfg)},
```

Spacing, punctuation, brackets, etc. are crucial and must be perfect. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Now:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20150923
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

You have compiled the driver for your currently installed kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a later linux-image, after the required reboot, please recompile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20150923
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Please retain the files and these instructions for that time.

Comment: This did it. Thanks so much for your help. That sucks that there are different subsystems; I figured that the 8260 number was what I needed to check on.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Any idea when the driver will support this pci.id and subsystem combination? Any way I can help make that happen?

Comment: No clue. I am not a developer; I am a tinkerer. I suggest you register and file a bug report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: @zck After you create a bug report, please ping me. I will send a patch upstream. Someone needs to do it. This way it will get to Ubuntu kernels sometime.

Comment: Dumb question but is this something that a udev rule could do rather than needing to patch the driver itself?

Comment: @Marplesoft Perhaps,but I'd have no idea how.

Comment: It is fixed in the wily kernel.

Comment: It is fixed in 4.2.0-17 and perhaps others in Wily's 4.2 series.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on 16.04 - if you have any thoughts, please [take a look](http://askubuntu.com/questions/819334/no-networks-listed-intel-8260-wireless-in-xenial).  Thanks!

Comment: @chili555 wonderful, this worked also on my Debian Jessie - thanks a lot!!!

Comment: small additional comment:  chili555 answer won't work unless you have done this: download firmware  (http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) copy iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode into /lib/firmware.

Comment: I'm using `BunsenLabs` linux on `Lenovo T560` and had the same problem. First tried to copy all the `ucode` files from here - https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware - to `/lib/firmware`, but no success. Then did the steps in this answer and all is fine now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

chili555's answer was certainly correct, but I haven't tested that. I'd just like to add that support is included in updated kernels for Ubuntu 15.10. When you're installing Ubuntu, wifi won't work to get you connected, but simply use a cable to get updates. Your wifi will work after a reboot. After updates, this worked out of the box on a Thinkpad P50.

So there's no need to download, edit and compile anything any more.

Answer (score 2):

To get this wireless adapter work in Ubuntu 15.10 you need to install firmware by running

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
```

For Ubuntu 14.04 you need also to upgrade the kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, depending on your laptop (mine yoga 900).
The module is compiled but network manager show it as disabled by hardware.

This is because the ideapad_laptop module thinks the laptop has a physical button to disable the wifi.

In that case, you can blacklist the module o recompile the kernel adding the equivalent section as described [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fa92a31b3335478c545cdc8e79e1e9b788184e6b).

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean everything will work in a new kernel release? Or should I still report a bug [as mentioned above](http://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network/697904#comment1012776_693165)?

Comment: This modification was done by hand, and I didn't see any bug report for it, so you should report it. The wireless driver modification is one thing, and other is the ideapad_laptop, both are related but belong to a two different bug reports

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the file `iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode` under `/lib/firmware`

You can find it [here](https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode).

download and run:

```
sudo cp <path-to-*.ucode file>/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode /lib/firmware
```

And now again:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20150923
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot:

`sudo reboot`

## intelnuc skull

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem of **unclaimed Intel wireless interface**.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on **Lenovo ideapad 520S** (which I recently bought). But the Wifi didn't work. The `lshw -c network` command displayed that the Intel wireless interface is unclaimed.

It seems Ubuntu 16.04 comes with v4.4 Kernel (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support#A16.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support).

After installing v4.13 Kernel, the problem has been solved.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.13.0 linux-headers-4.13.0 linux-image-extra-4.13.0
```