# How to activate NVIDIA Graphics card on Dell Precision 5510, Kubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, lightdm

NVIDIA card IS getting recognised and works on my Windows 7 partition. I just now have installed Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. Everything seems to work fine graphically. However by looking as `lspci` I have checked and seen that NVIDIA is not being used (should show up for VGA right?).

I have NVIDIA Quadro M1000M with 2GB DDR5 and Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics cards.

If I do:

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
```

I get:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics [8086:191b] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

If I do:

```
lspci | grep NVIDIA
```

I get:

```
3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev ff)
```

THIS PART SOLVED NOW (see comments):
I tried to activate this using bumblebee as in the instructions here : [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717465/installing-ubuntu-on-dell-precision-5510/765859#765859). Here it fails when I do the step `sudo service lightdm restart` and gives the error: `Failed to restart lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service not found.`

Comment: `lightdm` problem solved by trying with `sddm`. The original and MAIN problem of NVIDIA graphics card not detected automatically is still a lingering issue. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use sddm instead of lightdm. Sddm is the display manager used in recent versions of Kubutu.

```
sudo service sddm restart
```

You could also restart the PC which should have the same effect - the display manager will reload. 
If you followed the instructions correctly the NVIDIA graphics card should work then.

Comment: Yes that works, thank you. But the problem remains. I cannot get my Kubuntu 16.04 to recognise my NVIDIA Quadro M1000M. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the logs for any exceptions / errors? (Sorry for the late reply)