# wifi networks still not available

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, network-manager, broadcom

I posted this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798870/new-network-manager-crash-on-sony-laptop) yesterday but no-one has come to my assistance.

I really need to get the wifi networks working again on my Sony laptop.
I have spent all day today trawling through ask ubuntu and have tried may of the suggestions for getting my Broadcom BCM 43142 network controller working but without success.
I even reinstalled Trusty Tahr from scratch but my network controller still refuses to scan my home wifi network  - right now I'm connected via Ethernet, which works fine.

Please anyone HELP !!

Comment: Please don't post a new question to ask the same thing; you can just edit your old question with new information that you have.

Comment: @edwinski Sorry about polluting the forum with redundant questions (won't do it again), but I am losing my mind here.  Can you help with the specific problem?

Comment: Wifi is now BACK ! Not sure which of the many things I tried worked but I'm  up and running again. The mysteries of computing !

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the Broadcom BCM43142 with the Linux STA Wireless bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary) using **Additional drivers**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but  the necessary Linux Wireless bcmwl-kernel-source seems to be installed and working - the title is checked and the message is "this device is using an alternative driver". And yet still the option "Wifi Networks" in Network Manager is greyed out...

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, I solved it a month ago and I can't remember the details but here are the links I found useful:
[Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network)
[Installing Intel iwlwifi firmware for UNCLAIMED Wireless 8260?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697279/installing-intel-iwlwifi-firmware-for-unclaimed-wireless-8260)
[Installing Intel iwlwifi firmware for UNCLAIMED Wireless 8260?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697279/installing-intel-iwlwifi-firmware-for-unclaimed-wireless-8260)

I have a different wireless card than yours but I do remember a forum post specifically addressing this problem with broadcom, so google around.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Tyron Pretorius  Thanks for answering. Yes I would certainly prefer to have a clear "recipe" for my own specific wireless card. Can anyone help?