# Deleting module version: 7906 completely from the DKMS tree

Tags: drivers, kernel, 19.10, iwlwifi, dkms

I'm recently having issues with my WiFi which works a bit haphazardly, and I noticed while installing other apps that the issue seems to come from the `backport-iwlwifi-7906` package, but I'm not too sure how to fix it... I don't think I had this issue before switching to Ubuntu 19.10.

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/697279/720274) already, but in my case the network is recognised, so I'm not sure the fix quite applies in my case, and I don't want to risk totally breaking my WiFi by trying something without knowing if it's a good idea!

Here's my `lshw -C network` output for the appropriate device:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 3a
   serial: e4:a7:a0:cc:24:87
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-23-generic
       firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.1.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:129 memory:df000000-df001fff
```

And here my `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3]
    (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:1010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

And here is the full message I get when running `apt-get upgrade` when everything else has already been upgraded:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up backport-iwlwifi-dkms (7906-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing old backport-iwlwifi-7906 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 7906
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new backport-iwlwifi-7906 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-23-generic
Building initial module for 5.3.0-23-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17]
  File exists: '/var/crash/backport-iwlwifi-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package backport-iwlwifi-dkms (--configure):
 installed backport-iwlwifi-dkms package post-installation script subprocess
 returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 backport-iwlwifi-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thank you very much for helping, I'm not sure what other information might be useful so please do tell me if I should run any other commands to get more outputs!

**Edit:** after following heynnema's advice, here is the content from `/var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/make.log` (sorry I don't really understand this log, don't really know anything technical about Linux/Ubuntu, so I'm not sure which lines are relevant or not):

```
DKMS make.log for backport-iwlwifi-7906 for kernel 5.3.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Sat 23 Nov 15:34:09 EET 2019
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o zconf.tab.o zconf.tab.c
cc   conf.o zconf.tab.o   -o conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
make[5]: 'conf' is up to date.
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/compat/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/core.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/fw.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/compat/compat.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/mac80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/sysfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/status.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/driver-ops.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/radiotap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/nvm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/ops.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/sta_info.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/xvt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/phy-ctxt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/user-infc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/reg.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/wep.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/mac-ctxt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/aead_api.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/utils.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/utils.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/scan.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/fw.o
/var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/utils.c: In function ‘iwl_mvm_get_sync_time’:
/var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/utils.c:1468:14: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ktime_get_boot_ns’; did you mean ‘ktime_get_raw_ns’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 1468 |  *boottime = ktime_get_boot_ns();
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              ktime_get_raw_ns
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/scan.o
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[9]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/utils.o] Error 1
make[8]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm] Error 2
make[8]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/nvm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/rx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/nl80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/mlme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/offchannel.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/xvt/iwlxvt.o
make[7]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi] Error 2
make[6]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless/intel] Error 2
make[5]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/ht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/ibss.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/agg-tx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/agg-rx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/sme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/vht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/he.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/chan.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/ethtool.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/ibss.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/mesh.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/ap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/iface.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/trace.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/ocb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/pmsr.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/rate.o
  GEN     /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/shipped-certs.c
  GEN     /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/extra-certs.c
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/shipped-certs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/extra-certs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/michael.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/tkip.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/aes_cmac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/aes_gmac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/fils_aead.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/cfg.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/ethtool.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/rx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/spectmgmt.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/wireless/cfg80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/tx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/key.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/wme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/chan.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/trace.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/mlme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/tdls.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/ocb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/debugfs_sta.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/debugfs_netdev.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/debugfs_key.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/pm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/rc80211_minstrel.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/rc80211_minstrel_ht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/rc80211_minstrel_debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/rc80211_minstrel_ht_debugfs.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/net/mac80211/mac80211.o
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1655: _module_/var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile.build:6: modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile.real:100: modules] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:43: modules] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:30: default] Error 2
```

And here's `dkms status`:

```
backport-iwlwifi, 7906: added
```

Comment: Delete the crash log with `sudo rm -i /var/crash/backport-iwlwifi-dkms.0.crash` and then review `cat /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/7906/build/make.log` for details about the build failure. Then retry.

Comment: @heynnema I updated the question to include the content of this log, I still get the same error though, minus the `Cannot create report` line...

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status`.

Comment: Where did you get this backport driver, and why are you trying to install it? As @Pilot6 requests, lets see `dkms status`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added `dkms status`.

Comment: The driver is not installed but added. You can remove it by `sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/7906 --all`

Comment: @heynnema I didn't try and install it myself, it just came with my initial Ubuntu install I guess, but it only started throwing this error recently, pretty sure since I updated to 19.10

Comment: backports never "come" by themselves and never included in installation iso.

Comment: @Pilot6 is there a chance that the "automatically download updates" option when installing automatically downloads drivers for my firmware at the same time?

Comment: No, there is no such chance unless you added some PPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Pilot6's comment, I assumed that probably this package wasn't necessary, so did a sweet `sudo apt-get remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms`, which solved the issue. Still not sure how I got this package installed, but at least now everything seems alright!

Only thing I'm still unsure about: now `apt-get` is telling me that `dkms`is no longer required, is removing it safe? I thought `dkms` was a pretty central package, but again, I'm very much a newbie here.

Comment: You can remove `dkms` by `sudo apt autoremove` or individually. You don't need it if there are no dkms modules.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this module completely by

```
sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/7906 --all
```

If that doesn't work, you can manually remove it from dkms tree by

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi
```

**Be careful and don't make typos in this command, or it can remove something useful.**

This is quite safe to remove this way, because `dkms` doesn't store info in other places like `apt`.

Sources must be stored in `/usr/src`, you can remove from there as well, but it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: First command didn't resolve the problem, and second command told me that there was no such file/directory to remove...

Comment: You probably made a typo in the command. Please post output of `ls /var/lib/dkms`

Comment: And what did the first command output? Some error? Probably it already removed the directory.

Comment: First command output was the same as in the middle of my `apt-get upgrade` output in my post, no errors. No chance I made a typo, I was using autocompletion, which didn't work, then made sure to not make any typos in case my autocompletion was for some reason not completing. Here's the copy-paste of my command in history: `sudo apt-get remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms
`.  Only ran `ls` after `apt-get remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms`, there was only `dkms_dbversion` left after that.

Comment: If there is nothing there, then nothing is left in dkms tree.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

In my case, all the methods above did not work (after reboot, it appeared again). So, after I detached the wifi module from PC(Jetson Nano), it has been removed.