# Loading Wi-Fi Drivers by Configuring the Kernel

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kernel

I am new to Linux *using Ubuntu 14.04) and am having issues getting my wi-fi drivers to install. I found the appropriate files online and pasted them into the /lib/firmware directory as the install notes say. However, I am at a loss of words on how to load those drivers in the kernel. I've Googled and not come up with much at all. This is what the install notes say:

> The iwlwifi driver will look for the file iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode using
>   the kernel's firmware_class infrastructure. More information can be
>   found under Documentation/firmware_class in kernel source. In order to
>   function correctly, you need to have this support enabled in your
>   kernel.  When you configure the kernel, you can find this option in
>   the following location:
>
> Device Drivers ->
>                   Generic Driver Options ->
>                           Userspace firmware loading support
>
> You can determine if your kernel currently has firmware loader support
>   by looking for the CONFIG_FW_LOADER definition on your kernel's
>   .config.
>
> In addition to having the firmware_class support in your kernel, you
>   must also have a working udev and uevent infrastructure configured.
>   The steps for installing and configuring udev are very distribution
>   specific.
>
> Once you have the firmware loader in place (or if you aren't sure and
>   you just want to try things to see if it works), you need to install
>   the microcode file into the appropriate location.
>
> Where that appropriate location is depends (again) on your system
>   distribution.  You can typically find this location by looking in the
>   udev scripts of your distro, the default is /lib/firmware."

How do I do this?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I used this in hte terminal

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; uname -a
```

And I got the following information:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1130]
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1576]
```

From uname -a

```
Linux jeff-ThinkPad-P50 3.19.0-69-generic #77~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 30 01:29:21 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Where is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: @Pilot6 Just added it

Comment: @JorgeCastro No. It is outdated. Now kernel 4.4 supports it out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel is not supported any more and does not support the wireless adapter. You need to upgrade it. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

and reboot.

The wireless adapter should work if you updated the system and have the latest `linux-firmware` package.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer by looking elsewhere on this site. I found the answer here: [Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network)

I went to https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2016/03/24/backports-20160324.tar.gz

Extracted it, navigated to the directory in the terminal and performed the following commands, as outlined in the link I posted above.

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-2016324
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

I rebooted and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: You do not know which kernel OP is using. It is not good to suggest backports if there is a supported kernel for this device.

Comment: FrakkinShip is the OP however.