# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, intel-wireless

I'm having a hard time getting my [Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N7474CS) to work with my fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.3. There are similar questions to this, but all of the ones that I could find are dated. Currently, its not even showing any networks to connect to.

Here is some output that other posts (e.g. [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830881/loading-wi-fi-drivers-by-configuring-the-kernel)) led me to believe would be useful for helping solve this problem:

```
seth@desktop$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

seth@desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux desktop 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

seth@desktop:~$ ls /lib/firmware/
3com                         htc_7010.fw              iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode         rsi_91x.fw
4.10.0-28-generic            htc_9271.fw              iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode         rt2561.bin
4.10.0-42-generic            i2400m-fw-usb-1.4.sbcf   iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode         rt2561s.bin
a300_pfp.fw                  i2400m-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf   iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode          rt2661.bin
a300_pm4.fw                  i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf    iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode          rt2860.bin
acenic                       i915                     iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode          rt2870.bin
adaptec                      intel                    iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode          rt3070.bin
advansys                     intel-ucode              kaweth                         rt3090.bin
agere_ap_fw.bin              ipw2100-1.3.fw           keyspan                        rt3290.bin
agere_sta_fw.bin             ipw2100-1.3-i.fw         keyspan_pda                    rt73.bin
amdgpu                       ipw2100-1.3-p.fw         korg                           RTL8192E
ar3k                         ipw2200-bss.fw           lbtf_usb.bin                   rtl_bt
ar5523.bin                   ipw2200-ibss.fw          lgs8g75.fw                     rtl_nic
as102_data1_st.hex           ipw2200-sniffer.fw       libertas                       rtlwifi
as102_data2_st.hex           isci                     liquidio                       s2250.fw
asihpi                       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode     Makefile                       s2250_loader.fw
ath10k                       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode      matrox                         s5p-mfc.fw
ath3k-1.fw                   iwlwifi-105-6.ucode      mellanox                       s5p-mfc-v6.fw
ath6k                        iwlwifi-135-6.ucode      moxa                           s5p-mfc-v6-v2.fw
ath9k_htc                    iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode     mrvl                           s5p-mfc-v7.fw
atmel                        iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode     mt7601u.bin                    s5p-mfc-v8.fw
atmel_at76c504_2958.bin      iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode    mt7650.bin                     sb16
atmel_at76c504a_2958.bin     iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode    mts_cdma.fw                    scripts
atmsar11.fw                  iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode    mts_edge.fw                    sdd_sagrad_1091_1098.bin
atusb                        iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode    mts_gsm.fw                     slicoss
av7110                       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode    mts_mt9234mu.fw                sun
bnx2x                        iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode     mts_mt9234zba.fw               tehuti
brcm                         iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode     mwl8k                          ti_3410.fw
carl9170-1.fw                iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode     mwlwifi                        ti_5052.fw
carl9170fw                   iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode    myri10ge_eth_big_z8e.dat       ti-connectivity
cavium                       iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode    myri10ge_ethp_big_z8e.dat      tigon
cbfw-3.2.1.1.bin             iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode    myri10ge_ethp_z8e.dat          ti-keystone
cbfw-3.2.3.0.bin             iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode    myri10ge_eth_z8e.dat           tlg2300_firmware.bin
cbfw-3.2.5.1.bin             iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode     myri10ge_rss_eth_big_z8e.dat   ttusb-budget
cis                          iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode     myri10ge_rss_ethp_big_z8e.dat  ueagle-atm
configure                    iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode     myri10ge_rss_ethp_z8e.dat      usbdux
cpia2                        iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode     myri10ge_rss_eth_z8e.dat       usbduxfast_firmware.bin
ct2fw-3.2.1.1.bin            iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode     netronome                      usbdux_firmware.bin
ct2fw-3.2.3.0.bin            iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode  NPE-B                          usbduxsigma_firmware.bin
ct2fw-3.2.5.1.bin            iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode  NPE-C                          v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw
ctefx.bin                    iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode  nvidia                         v4l-cx23418-apu.fw
ctfw-3.2.1.1.bin             iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode     ositech                        v4l-cx23418-cpu.fw
ctfw-3.2.3.0.bin             iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode    phanfw.bin                     v4l-cx23418-dig.fw
ctfw-3.2.5.1.bin             iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode    qat_895xcc.bin                 v4l-cx2341x-dec.fw
ctspeq.bin                   iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode    qat_895xcc_mmp.bin             v4l-cx2341x-enc.fw
cxgb3                        iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode    qat_c3xxx.bin                  v4l-cx2341x-init.mpg
cxgb4                        iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode    qat_c3xxx_mmp.bin              v4l-cx23885-avcore-01.fw
dsp56k                       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode    qat_c62x.bin                   v4l-cx25840.fw
dvb-fe-xc4000-1.4.1.fw       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode     qat_c62x_mmp.bin               v4l-pvrusb2-24xxx-01.fw
dvb-fe-xc5000-1.6.114.fw     iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode     qat_mmp.bin                    v4l-pvrusb2-29xxx-01.fw
dvb-fe-xc5000c-4.1.30.7.fw   iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode     qca                            vicam
dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw      iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode    qcom                           vntwusb.fw
dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw         iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode    qed                            vpu_d.bin
dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw         iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode    ql2100_fw.bin                  vpu_p.bin
dvb-usb-terratec-h5-drxk.fw  iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode    ql2200_fw.bin                  vxge
ea                           iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode    ql2300_fw.bin                  WHENCE.ubuntu
edgeport                     iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode     ql2322_fw.bin                  whiteheat.fw
emi26                        iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode     ql2400_fw.bin                  whiteheat_loader.fw
emi62                        iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode   ql2500_fw.bin                  wil6210.brd
ene-ub6250                   iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode   r128                           wil6210.fw
ess                          iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode   r8a779x_usb3_v1.dlmem          wsm_22.bin
f2255usb.bin                 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode   r8a779x_usb3_v2.dlmem          yam
go7007                       iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode   r8a779x_usb3_v3.dlmem          yamaha
GPL-3                        iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode   radeon                         zd1201-ap.fw
hfi1_dc8051.fw               iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode   README                         zd1201.fw
hfi1_fabric.fw               iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode   rp2.fw                         zd1211
hfi1_pcie.fw                 iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode   RS9113_AP_BT_DUAL_MODE.rps
hfi1_sbus.fw                 iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode   RS9113_WLAN_BT_DUAL_MODE.rps
hp                           iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode   RS9113_WLAN_QSPI.rps
```

The information on [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) Intel site leads me to believe that the `iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode` should be making this work, but its not.

**Edit:** Outputs of more commands, as requested:

```
seth@desktop:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
seth@desktop:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    1.828348] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.844321] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.608620.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.856324] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    1.857417] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    1.857637] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.068873] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.069769] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.228905] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.229125] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.439776] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.439995] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
```

**edit 2: ** and some more...

```
seth@desktop:~$ sudo iwlist scan
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

seth@desktop:~$ iwconfig
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

**Edit 3:** yet more...

```
seth@desktop:~$ dmesg | grep wlp
[    2.069769] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.226853] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[    2.462231] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[    2.571468] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Looks perfect so far! How about: `sudo iwlist scan` Don't tell us the whole result; just tell us if it scans or throws a message. Also: `iwconfig`

Comment: @chili555 done. Unfortunately, the output was short enough to give the whole thing.

Comment: "Device or resource busy" Busy?? Weird. Let's dig deeper: `dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: Done again. What are we looking for here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70999/discussion-between-chili555-and-setholopolus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our discussion in chat, and seeing nothing else incorrect, it appears that in connecting the PCIe mini-to-PCIe adapter, the antenna wire was either not connected or wiggled loose. You opened the computer and connected the antenna firmly and the wireless is working!