# New HP Spectre x360 Wifi Not Working using Intel 8265 Card

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, network-manager, intel-wireless

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP laptop today, but I'm unable to connect to any networks. Network manager shows an option to Enable Networking but not to Enable Wireless, and says "No network devices available" (this was the same even on USB boot).

I ran `sudo lshw -C network` and got `*-network UNCLAIMED`, `configuration:`. I tried `lspci`, `lsmod`, but got no result. Finally, `sudo iwconfig` gave `lo      no wireless extensions.`

I've been stuck on this all day and tried many solutions, including [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network). One of the biggest problems is that my laptop doesn't have an ethernet port and I don't have an adapter.

I saw some older questions about the Intel 8265 card, but most of them said it wasn't supported yet because it was new, however, these sites: [[1]](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html), [[2]](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) say that it is supported since a recent kernel.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless device, the Intel 8265, is indeed supported in later kernel versions; specifically 4.6 and later. Ubuntu 16.04 uses the slightly older 4.4.0-xx kernel. You can verify from the terminal:

```
uname -r
```

I recommend that you install Ubuntu 16.10 which runs kernel version 4.8.0-xx and fully supports your device.