# How to get Intel 18265 Wifi Card working on Lenovo X1 Carbon running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lenovo, thinkpad, intel-wireless

I've just got a Lenovo X1 Carbon (5th generation). When I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS off an USB the Wifi was working from the point go.

However at some point during the setup process the Wifi card stopped working. The card is identified as a `Intel WiGig 18265AC+BT 2x2 vPro` in the specsheet.

The network dropdown on the system bar reads:

```
Wi-Fi Networks 
device not ready 
Mobile Broadband 
not enabled
```

Bluetooth is not accessible either. I've had a look around via Google but haven't found any solution that works.

What is the best approach to get this up and running?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't *8265*? Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/854858/new-hp-spectre-x360-wifi-not-working-using-intel-8265-card

Comment: Also please see: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/tri-band-wireless-ac-18265.html Especially: "The Intel® Tri-Band Wireless-AC 18265 includes Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265  for 802.11ac, dual-band, 2x2 Wi-Fi + Bluetooth* 4.2 connectivity..."

Comment: @chill555 - I hadn't seen that 8265 is contained in 18265, but I had tried installing the drivers because of the similarity in model numbers. I'm running kernel: 4.8.0-41-generic - which theoretically supports the 8265.

Comment: Let's see a full diagnostic, please: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: The Intel 18265AC card is Tri-band, with 802.11ad WiGig. Does Linux support WiGig with recent kernels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 all of the network functions worked:

- Ethernet
- Wifi
- Mobile Broadband
- Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

I had a simiar problem, except that wifi never worked for me, even using the USB drive. What worked for me was changing kernel to the most recent one that I found available using

```
apt-cache search linux-image-extra
```

I changed kernel using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.11.0-14-generic linux-headers-4.11.0-14-generic linux-image-extra-4.11.0-14-generic
```

(But using the commands suggested in another comment here

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo service network-manager restart
```

did fix my bluetooth, so thanks!)

Answer (score -1):

In the end the following commands got me up and running:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo service network-manager restart
```

At a guess there were conflicting unused drivers.