# Offline installation of Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on ThinkPad X1 Carbon 2018. With no Ethernet, how to get Wifi driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, system-installation, ubuntu-mate

Wifi chip is `Intel Dual band Wireless AC 8265`.

In general, what could be done to get required drivers on a machine after offline installation of a distro?

Comment: AC8265 is a [notorious](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094226/) [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895872/) with no single easy solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.