# No WiFi on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, when I boot into the system, I cannot find any wireless connections

[image]

I tried `rfkill list` and it displays:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo lshw -C network` displays:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: a0:d3:c1:9c:37:47
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.3-4 ip=192.168.2.129 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 memory:d0700000-d071ffff memory:d073e000-d073efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0500000-d0503fff
```

Here's what I have tried: I have run `sudo apt-get update` and in my 'Software and Updates' -> Additional Drivers, [i have selected the Broadcom drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAEkF.png). I booted the system and none of this seems to work. What can I do?

Comment: Your `sudo lshw -C network` displays `*-network UNCLAIMED`.  Please refer the post [Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network) so that you get an idea to resolve your issue!

Comment: It will not fix his Broadcom device to intall an Intel driver! @Marmayogi

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` A little bird told me it is secure boot! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That is not my point @chili555. I suggested to the questioner to get an idea about `network UNCLAIMED` and how it is is solved in the case of Intel driver. I hope you see my point.

Comment: Please edit the question and post the output of the following commands: 1. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` and 2. `mokutil --sb-state`