# Wifi does not work with my Dell Latitude E5270 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, intel, iwlwifi

I found a post with a similar issue for Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260 chip set, but cannot follow the recommended steps for Ubuntu 20.04:
[Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network)

It suggests compiling the driver for a different pci.id:  (IWL_PCI_DEVICE(0x24F3, 0x1130, iwl8260_2ac_cfg)

Now make defconfig-iwlwifi   > fails with: Generating local configuration database from kernel ...Kernel version parse failed!

Which driver do I need to use/modify for Ubuntu 20.04?

Diagnostics:

```
arnulf@Ubuntu-Latitude-E5270:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
arnulf@Ubuntu-Latitude-E5270:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.180549] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.180551] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.181174] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.259955] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    3.268283] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.269298] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.351006] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 34:f3:9a:a0:92:ae
[    3.424863] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.671817] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
arnulf@Ubuntu-Latitude-E5270:~$ 

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Your wireless device is now working according to the log.

Comment: It seems to be working: *Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi* Are there any clues here? `rfkill list all` or: `dmesg | grep wlp`

Answer (score 0):

[Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network) should have the answer to this problem, but if it doesn't tell me and I will check.

Comment: I tried following https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network, but failed.

What do I need to do instead of:
Please download this file to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/09/23/backports-20150923.tar.gz 
if using a lter version of Ubuntu. I'm on 20.04.

Comment: make clean results in:
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...Kernel version parse failed!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-initial-check.html.en could be a helpful link but also check that the wireless switch is in the on position.

Comment: Any idea how to get Wifi running in Dell Latitude E5270 with Ubuntu 20.04?